# Nvarchar casting as integer error... when no integer column used

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a piece of code that worked when my customer numbers were all numeric. So customer numbers have been added that are alpha now and I get a "The conversion of the nvarchar value ' 4000545398' overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded" error which I know is over the 2.1million etc...
My issue lay in that number 4000545398 is a lot number in the very first record of table shipper_sii [ a nvarchar (10)].

Columns in my tables are as follows...

```
custaddr - name (nvarchar (60)), cust_num (nvarchar(7))
co - cust_num (nvarchar(7)), co_num (nvarchar(10))
shipper_sii - co_num (nvarchar(10)), lot (nvarchar(15))
```

my declarations are...

```
 Dim Carton1 As String
 Dim dbCustName As String
 Dim dbCustNum As String
```

Anyone have a fix for me? I am scratching my head here...
 I am pretty sure its in my join, but I am stumped...

```
' Get Customer Name

Using connObj2 As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=Server;database=App;uid=sa;pwd=password;")
  Using cmdObj2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT c2.name, c2.cust_num from custaddr as c2 INNER JOIN co as c1 ON (c2.cust_num = c1.cust_num) INNER JOIN shipper_sii as s1 on (c1.co_num = s1.co_num) WHERE lot = " & Carton1, connObj2)
    connObj2.Open()
    Using readerObj2 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmdObj2.ExecuteReader
        'This will loop through all returned records 
        While readerObj2.Read

            dbCustNum = readerObj2("cust_num").ToString
            dbCustName = readerObj2("name").ToString
            'handle returned value before next loop here

        End While
    End Using
    connObj2.Close()
  End Using
End Using
```

My error pops at the "While readerObj2.Read".

Comment: What is the value of `Carton1` when you get here? Why don't you use sql-parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a parameterized query to avoid this kind of errors and [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) problems

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT c2.name, c2.cust_num from custaddr as c2 " & _
                "INNER JOIN co as c1 ON (c2.cust_num = c1.cust_num)  " & _
                "INNER JOIN shipper_sii as s1 on (c1.co_num = s1.co_num)  " & _
                "WHERE lot = @car"
Using cmdObj2 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, connObj2)
     cmdObj2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car",  Carton1)
   .....
```

Here `lot` is a NVarChar field, so, in a string concatenation this requires the quotes around the `Carton1` variable, but with a parameterized query you avoid that problem.